# Disadvantages of Materialized View

Tags: oracle

I have been use Materialized View in Oracle11g.By Using this View, Can growth to Database size?Please let me know,disadvantages of MV.

Comment: Materialized views are there to decrease the query execution time by pre computing the result. As you are getting the results that are already calculated there is an issue of slight variation with actual data. But if you are aware of how underlying tables are changing then you can use MVIEW to great effect.

Comment: MView can take place in DB size?

Comment: Yes, Mview creates a physical table with all the data.

Comment: Thank  ILLUMINATI7590

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A materialised view is best thought of as three basic components:

**

> 1. A query that defines a result set
> 2. A table to store the result of the query in, and whatever supporting indexes you add to it.
> 3. Metadata that controls the way in which the result set is refreshed, whether the result set can be used for query rewrite or
>      not, the state of the metadata, etc..

**

So, evidently the table and indexes are indeed going to use space.

I'm afraid that you really need to go and read the documentation for your version to understand these basic concepts, as the answer to your question is derived from basic of knowledge of what a materialised view actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Materialized views are tables created(/updated) by a select at a specific time. So yes, they take some space in DB.

Learn all about Materialized view : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96567/repmview.htm